# draw the y-label on the top of y axis

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I want draw the ylab on the top of the y axis, which code can I use?

Here is the example

```
par(mar=c(4,6,4,4))
plot(rnorm(100), ylab="")
mtext(side=2, text="Label", las=1, line=2)
```

I want draw the ylabel at the top of y axis which red arrow indicated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this, by finding the top left corner and fixing it to it.

```
par(mar=c(4,6,4,4))
plot(rnorm(100), ylab="")

loc <- par("usr")
text(loc[1], loc[4], "Label", pos = 2, xpd = T)
```

Playing around with `pos` and adding `adj` could change the position a bit.

[image]